# how to receive a vlc flow in a socket?

Tags: sockets, tcl, vlc

I'm developping a streaming application with tcl.
I have a vlc sever that broadcast a flow in http mode. what I'm trying to do is to develop a client who will try to connect to server with a particular ip adress and port number, and then try to save the flow in a file.
the code that i'm using is simple:

```
set server localhost
set sockChan [socket $server 1234]
set line [read $sockChan 1000]
puts " vidéo: $line"
close $sockChan
```

the problem when i try to test my script, I see that I realise the connection, but I can't read the flow!
the 'puts' doesn't show anything in the console...

Have you any ideas!
thank you..

Comment: VLC might buffer.  Try reading 1024 bytes (or some multiple of 1024).

Comment: I tried your solution... I still have the same problem ...

Answer (score 2):

If you're just wanting to save the contents of a URL to a file, the standard [`http`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/http.htm#M16) package has a `-channel` option which lets you dump directly. For example:

```
package require http
set f [open video.dump w]
fconfigure $f -translation binary
set tok [http::geturl "http://server:port/url" -channel $f]
close $f
if {[http::ncode $tok] != 200} {
    # failed somehow...
} else {
    # succeeded
}
http::cleanup $tok
```

**Edit:** Doing it asynchronously (requires the event loop going, e.g. via `vwait forever`):

```
package require http
set f [open video.dump w]
fconfigure $f -translation binary
proc done {f tok} {
    close $f
    if {[http::ncode $tok] != 200} {
        # failed somehow...
    } else {
        # succeeded
    }
    http::cleanup $tok
}    
http::geturl "http://server:port/url" -channel $f -command "done $f"
# Your code runs here straight away...
```

Note that the code's recognizably similar, but now in a slightly different order! If you've got Tcl 8.5 — if not, why not? — then you can use a lambda application instead to make the apparent order of the code even more similar:

```
package require http
set f [open video.dump w]
fconfigure $f -translation binary
http::geturl "http://server:port/url" -channel $f -command [list apply {{f tok} {
    close $f
    if {[http::ncode $tok] != 200} {
        # failed somehow...
    } else {
        # succeeded
    }
    http::cleanup $tok
}} $f]
# Your code runs here straight away...
```

Comment: Thank you it's working very well...
But when the script is downloading the file, I haven't access to the same file! 
In fact, I need to stream a file in http mode and forward for someone else! here I have to wait the end of streaming. What I need is to read the stream by bytes and forward it in the same time!

any other ideas please!

Comment: You should have said so before. If you don't want to keep the bytes yourself but can't wait, pass in a `-command` to `geturl` and you'll get an asynchronous callback when it's all done. In the meantime, you can do other things. I'll update the answer with a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with HTTP, I would suggest looking at [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/tcl/) bindings for TCL.